# How can I manage reference in a recursive table?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to manage reference on a recursive table to get the followers of an user.

I had try @JsonBackReference and @JsonManagedReference but it doesn't work for me, perhaps because i don't know where i should put it exactically.

```
public class User implements Serializable {

    ...

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<User> followers;

    ...

}
```

When I get the user I get all followers of their followers, but i only want to get their own followers. How can I do that? There is some annotation to do this?

Comment: What exactly you're trying to do? Can you show some code where you use these Users? Did you get some exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are asking how to use `Jackson` to handle such situation such that the output JSON will only contain user 's followers , but not user 's follower 's followers...... If yes , you can use `@JsonIgnoreProperties` to break the recursive cycle:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties("followers")
private List<User> followers;
```